# JsonSchema: Optional properties based on value

Tags: jsonschema

I'm trying to create a schema for the config file that supports [Gaspar](https://github.com/wckdrzr/gaspar).

Here is a part of the schema I have built (with some properties removed to make it easier to read):

```json
"Output": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [ "Type" ],
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "Type": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [ "CSharp", "TypeScript" ]
            },
            "ModelNamespaces": {
                "type": "array",
                "description": "CSharp Only",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "AddInferredNullables": {
                "type": "boolean",
                "description": "TypeScript Only",
            }
        }
    }
},
```

As you can see, I've set `additionalProperties` to false as I want miss-spellings to be highlighted.  But I'm struggling with making some properties available only when the enum is set:

`ModelNamespaces` is always optional, but only valid when `Type` is set to "CSharp"

`AddInferredNullables` is always optional, but is only valid when `Type` is set to "TypeScript"

All of the examples I can find seem to be about changing the `required` status depending on a value; but these properties will always be optional, I would just like it highlighted as incorrect if the `Type` is "TypeScript" and the user includes `ModelNamepaces`.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: when you say highlighted, are you trying to use the validation output somewhere or you want the data instance to fail validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `if, then` syntax with JSON Schema draft-07 or newer.

You'll find the `Type` schema is defined at the root with the enum constraints, but this keyword must also be redefined in the `then` schema of the conditional statement. Defining it as a boolean schema is sufficient for the validator to recognize this keyword exists and the constraints at the root will be validated.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Output": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "Type"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "Type": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "CSharp",
              "TypeScript"
            ]
          }
        },
        "allOf": [
          {
            "if": {
              "properties": {
                "Type": {
                  "const": "TypeScript"
                }
              }
            },
            "then": {
              "properties": {
                "Type": true,
                "AddInferredNullables": {
                  "type": "boolean",
                  "description": "TypeScript Only"
                }
              },
              "additionalProperties": false
            }
          },
          {
            "if": {
              "properties": {
                "Type": {
                  "const": "CSharp"
                }
              }
            },
            "then": {
              "properties": {
                "Type": true,
                "ModelNamespaces": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "description": "CSharp Only",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              },
              "additionalProperties": false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Passing instances:

```json
{
  "Output": [
    {
      "Type": "TypeScript"    
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "Output": [
    {
      "Type": "TypeScript",
      "AddInferredNullables": true   
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "Output": [
    {
      "Type": "CSharp"
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "Output": [
    {
      "Type": "CSharp",
      "ModelNamespaces": ["something", "anotherThing"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Failing instances:

```json
{
  "Output": [
    {
      "Type": "TypeScript",
      "ModelNamespaces": []
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "Output": [
    {
      "Type": "JavaScript"
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "Output": [
    {
      "Type": "CSharp",
      "AddInferredNullables": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Amazing; thank you!  Exactly what I was hoping for

Answer (score 0):

There is no "elegant" solution to this as far as I can see. This one should be working from at least Draft-04 up to now (Draft 2020-12) and might be the most brief while being still readable.

```json
"Output": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "oneOf": [
            {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "Type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [ "CSharp" ]
                    },
                    "ModelNamespaces": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "description": "CSharp Only",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "required": ["Type"], 
                "additionalProperties": false
            },
            {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "Type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [ "TypeScript" ]
                    },
                    "AddInferredNullables": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "description": "TypeScript Only"
                    }
                },
                "required": ["Type"], 
                "additionalProperties": false
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

The basic idea is to limit the two possible valid schemas to one of the enum values (consider these enum definitions quasi constants) and only allowing the dependent property in each case. Note that `"additionalproperties": false` needs to go in each of the possible schemas, since it's evaluated on its schema only, not any composition or such.